# How to render property name of JSON object with JsRender?

Tags: jsrender

I have a JSON object with dynamic property name. How can I render the property name with JsRender? I have been looking at the samples from JsRender demo page but couldn't find a way to do so.

Example:

```
{
    'prop1': '123',
    'prop2': '456'
}
```

Expected output:

```
1. prop1 = 123
2. prop3 = 456
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kvuZC/

**UPDATE** Working JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B76WP/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate through field with helper

```
$.views.helpers({
    getFields: function( object ) {
        var key, value,
            fieldsArray = [];
        for ( key in object ) {
            if ( object.hasOwnProperty( key )) {
                value = object[ key ];
                // For each property/field add an object to the array, with key and value
                fieldsArray.push({
                    key: key,
                    value: value
                });
            }
        }
        // Return the array, to be rendered using {{for ~fields(object)}}
        return fieldsArray;
    }
});
```

Code from  ['Iterating through fields' scenario](http://borismoore.github.io/jsrender/demos/scenarios/03_iterating-through-fields-scenario.html)

```
{{for ~getFields(details)}}
   <b>{{>key}}</b>: {{>value}}
{{/for}}
```

Comment: Good and useful explanation of how to set up a helper, but as `props` has since been added to jsRender, this particular use case is now obsolete. See Alex's answer for the modern way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

check the {{props}} tag, it is very useful to solve this question.
https://www.jsviews.com/#propstag

```
{{props}}
    1. {{>key}} = {{>prop}}
{{/props}}
```

and the output will be the desired.

Answer (score 2):

Change approach. Map your object in array of objects that will hold your key and value.

This is code that should do that:

```
var jsonData = {
    'prop1': '123',
    'prop2': '456'
}
, data = $.map(jsonData, function(value, key) {return {value: value, key: key}});

$('#container').html($('#dynamicObjectTemplate').render(data));
```

This will create following:

```
[{
  value: '123',
  key: 'prop1'
},{
  value: '456',
  key: 'prop2'
}]
```

And here is working example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kvuZC/1/) (Couldn't include jsrender code via reference, so I pasted it... your code is at the bottom)